# Django says all Images invalid, but PIL works

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, python-imaging-library, django-models, gunicorn

I'm running a new Linode on Ubuntu 12.04 with Nginx, Gunicorn, and Django 1.4. Uploading to an imagefield (which works locally) claims the file is corrupt or invalid, including for images that work locally.

PIL works. I can load, check, and collect various properties of an image.

I'm also using a virtualenv.

Any suggestions?

**More Information:**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL 1.1.7 SETUP SUMMARY
--------------------------------------------------------------------
version       1.1.7
platform      linux2 2.7.3 (default, Apr 20 2012, 22:44:07)
              [GCC 4.6.3]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
*** TKINTER support not available
*** JPEG support not available
*** ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support not available
*** FREETYPE2 support not available
*** LITTLECMS support not available
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is output at the end of pip install PIL. The question is, why is support for nothing available?

Answer (score 2):

Solved using the following: http://www.sandersnewmedia.com/why/2012/04/16/installing-pil-virtualenv-ubuntu-1204-precise-pangolin/

---

#### For archival purposes, a copy of the post:

The following technique should work for both 32-bit and 64-bit systems.

Install the build dependencies:

`sudo apt-get build-dep python-imaging`

Symlink the libraries:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/`uname -i`-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so /usr/lib/
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/`uname -i`-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib/
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/`uname -i`-linux-gnu/libz.so /usr/lib/
```

Install:

```
pip install PIL
```

You should see something like this after it builds:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL 1.1.7 SETUP SUMMARY
--------------------------------------------------------------------
version       1.1.7
platform      linux2 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 22:21:37)
              [GCC 4.6.3]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
--- TKINTER support available
--- JPEG support available
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
--- FREETYPE2 support available
*** LITTLECMS support not available
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution which worked for me.

1. Install the following

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libjpeg62-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev
   ```
2. Goto your virtual env

   ```
   cd ~/.virtualenvs/{env-name}
   ```
3. Symlink the libs to your environment

   *For 32-bit systems:*

   ```
   ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so ./lib/
   ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so ./lib/
   ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so ./lib/
   ```

   *For 64-bit systems:*

   ```
   ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so ./lib/
   ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so ./lib/
   ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so ./lib/
   ```
4. install PIL (note - if already installed then uninstall it and then re-install)

   ```
   pip install PIL
   ```